# Advanced generics in Typescript, function parameter restrictions

Tags: typescript, migration, storage, versioning

I want to write an application which can deal with different versions of data. In order to do so, it has to migrate from one version to the next.

Given the following two schemas

```
const schemaV1 = {
  users: {
    // ...
  },
};

const schemaV2 = {
  users: {
    // ...
  },
  comments: {
    // ...
  },
};
```

Now, I want to write a function `createMigrator`, which takes an array of schemas as input along with an `upgrade` function for each next version, so that transitions between two versions are type-safe.

The function call should look like this:

```
const migrator = createMigrator({
  versions: [
    // v1
    {
      schema: schemaV1,
    },

    // v2
    {
      schema: schemaV2,
      upgrade: (prev) => {
        // prev should be of type schemaV1
      }
    },
  ] as const,
});
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
interface Options<T> {
  versions: VersionInit<T>;
}

interface BaseVersion<T> {
  schema: T;
}

interface VersionWithUpgrade<T, Prev> extends BaseVersion<T> {
  upgrade: (prev: Prev) => void;
}

type VersionInit<T> = T extends readonly [infer U, ...infer Tail]
  ? [BaseVersion<U>, ...VersionNext<U, Tail>]
  : [];

type VersionNext<Prev, T> = T extends readonly [infer U, ...infer Tail]
  ? [VersionWithUpgrade<U, Prev>, ...VersionNext<U, Tail>]
  : [];

function createMigrator<T>(options: Options<T>) {
  // TODO
}
```

I expected it to allow `options` to only match the shape passed in the function call, but my Typescript compiler complains `The type 'readonly [{ readonly schema: { users: {}; }; }, { readonly schema: { users: {}; comments: {}; }; readonly upgrade: (prev: any) => void; }]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '[]'.`

Can you give me any hints how to accomplish that?

Comment: The `readonly` error seems to be a red herring; you could easily fix that by making your tuples `readonly` everywhere, but that's not going to fix your problem.

Comment: If you require `createMigrator` to be variadic in the length of the `versions` property, then you'll never get the `prev` callback param types to be inferred contextually; see [ms/TS#47393](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47393).  If you're okay with a solution requiring you to *annotate* `prev`, I can explore that.  Or if you're okay with a solution which only handles up to some modest max array length, I can explore that. How would you like to proceed?

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for your reply and the link! Actually I'd like to give as few type hints as possible. Regarding some modest max array length, are you talking about overloading the function with a hand-crafted amount of types or are you talking about the max recursion depth?

Comment: I’m talking about the length of the `versions` array.  Yes, overloads would be the way that would happen (you’ll never get a single generic variadic tuple type to have inference from one element type to the next).